# Using Galilean transformation to solve a question with a block-spring-block system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, spring

I am currently practicing for my PHYS 101 major test and encountered this question:

> In Figure 11, block 1 (mass 2.50 kg) is moving rightward at 10.0 m/s
> and block 2 (mass
> 6.20 kg) is moving rightward at 3.00 m/s. The horizontal surface is frictionless, and a spring with a spring constant of 960 N/m is fixed
> to block 2. When the blocks collide, the compression of the spring is
> maximum at the instant the blocks have the same velocity. Find the
> velocity of blocks when the spring compression is maximum. (Neglect
> the mass of spring) [image]
>
> A) 5.01 m/s
>
> B) 3.50 m/s
>
> C) 5.85 m/s
>
> D) 4.50 m/s
>
> E) 2.08 m/s

The solution provided uses conservation of momentum to find $v_f$
$$m_1v_1+m_2v_2=(m_1+m_2)v_f$$
where solving for $v_f$ and plugging in the numbers yields $v_f=5.01\text{m/s}$

However my attempted solution goes as follows:

First write down equation of energy conservation for the instant where the two blocks have the same velocity.
$$ \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 + \frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)v_f^2$$
We're missing one piece of information to solve for $v_f$ and that's $x$. However if we use block 2 as our reference frame, then we could use conservation of energy again to find $x$ and then plug in in our original equation to solve for $v_f$.

Using energy conservation for block 2 as our frame of reference, we get: $$\frac{1}{2}m_1v_{1,2}^2=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$ where $v_{1,2}^2=v_1-v_2=7 \text{m/s}$

Now substituting $\frac{1}{2}m_1v_{1,2}^2$ for $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ in our original equation yields $$ \frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 = \frac{1}{2}m_1v_{1,2}^2 + \frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)v_f^2$$

Where solving for $v_f$ and plugging in yields $v_f=4.59\text{m/s}$ which, obviously, is not the right answer. However, I fail to see where my approach fails. I suspect that it has to do with the velocity of block 2 changing while the spring is being contracted, but I fail to fully grasp why that would be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you anticipated, your argument breaks down because Block 2 is accelerating, so there is no inertial frame corresponding to "the frame of Block 2."

To see that it must be accelerating, first consider that initially, when Block 1 hits the spring, the spring must contract. It will take a finite time for the spring to contract to its maximum contraction, before it will push back on Block 1.

During the time that the spring is contracting, it must be exerting a net force on Block 2. Block 2 must be exerting a force on the right end of the spring to cause it to contract and prevent it from moving at the same speed as the left end of the block. By Newton's third law, if Block 2 is exerting a force on the spring, then the spring must be exerting a force on Block 2. Further there are no other forces acting on Block 2, so there is a non-zero net force acting on Block 2. Therefore, Block 2 is accelerating.

Block 2 is also accelerating as the spring uncompresses from its maximum compression (but in the opposite direction), for similar reasons.